# SQL Server : CTE going a level back in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I would like to set a limit to a recursive query. But I don't want to lose the last entry on which i limited the recursion.

Right now the query looks like this:

```
WITH MyCTE (EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, ManagerID, level, SPECIAL)
AS ( 
    SELECT a.EmployeeID, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.ManagerID, 0 as Level
    FROM MyEmployees as a
    WHERE ManagerID IS NULL

    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.EmployeeID, b.FirstName, b.LastName, b.ManagerID, level + 1
    FROM MyEmployees as b
    INNER JOIN MyCTE ON b.ManagerID = MyCTE.EmployeeID
    WHERE b.ManagerID IS NOT NULL and b.LastName != 'Welcker' 
)
SELECT *
FROM MyCTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 25)
```

And it gets limited by the Manager Welcker, the result looks like this:

```
EmployeeID; FirstName; LastName; ManagerID; level
1           Ken        Sánchez   NULL       0
```

What I want is to have the employee 'Welcker' included. The problem is I only have the name of the last person I need to have on my list. There are some entries below in the command structure but I don't know them and I don't want to see them.

Here's a example of how I imagine the result of my query to look.

```
EmployeeID FirstName LastName ManagerID level
1          Ken       Sánchez  NULL        0
273        Brian     Welcker  1           1
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH MyCTE (EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, ManagerID, level, NotMatched)
AS ( 
    SELECT a.EmployeeID, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.ManagerID, 0 as Level, 0 AS NotMatched
    FROM MyEmployees as a
    WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.EmployeeID, b.FirstName, b.LastName, b.ManagerID, level + 1,
           CASE WHEN (MyCTE.LastName = 'Welcker' AND MyCTE.level = 1) THEN 1 ELSE MyCTE.NotMatched END
    FROM MyEmployees as b
    INNER JOIN MyCTE ON b.ManagerID = MyCTE.EmployeeID
)
SELECT *
FROM MyCTE
WHERE NotMatched != 1
```

Comment: I will try this when I am back at the Office :) It seems very simple :)

Comment: If I do this and use a diferent lastname from a lower level in the cte. I just get the level 0 employee! What i want is a limit like Maxrecursion but with a value. Like option (stop at 'rndLastname') And then the CTE stops on this path. For example, I have a user called Sanchez which is the Owner of the buissnes and 4 head of departments. What I want is to see 3 of the head of departments including their employees but not the employees of the 4th manager. But the manager needs to be displayed! This example make not much sense in this context but I think its clear what I want to do

Comment: With this one I lose every Entry below the Level of 'Welcker'. Even they don't have 'Welcker' as Manager. But I still need these. Only the one who have 'Welcker' as Manager should be gone. But we get closer :)

Comment: Its working now with one of your versions before thank you very much. I still dont know why it works now. I use WHERE MyCTE.LastName != 'Jiang' without the -Level thing! I still dont know why it works but it does!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you just change that one line to `b.LastName = 'Welcker'`?

Comment: Does 'OPTION (MAXRECURSION 25)' change the behavior of 'level + 1'? That'd be crazy!

Comment: There are 10 other employees and some of them can change during the year. basicly it should stop going deeper in the structur when welcker comes up but still show the entry. dont know if I made myself clear :S

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct
   t.b_eid as empId,
   t.b_name as name, 
   case t.b_mid when 0 then null else t.b_mid end as managerId

   --convert(varchar,t.b_eid) + ', ' + 
   --t.b_name + ', ' + 
   --case t.b_mid when '0' then 'null' else convert(varchar,t.b_mid) end
      --as bvals

from(
   select
      coalesce(a.mid, 0) as a_mid,
      a.eid as a_eid,
      a.name as a_name,
      coalesce(b.mid, 0) as b_mid,
      b.eid as b_eid,
      b.name as b_name
   from 
      (values(null,1,'adam'),(null,2,'barb'),(201,3,'chris')) as a(mid,eid,name) cross join 
      (values(null,1,'adam'),(null,2,'barb'),(201,3,'chris')) as b(mid,eid,name)
) as t
where (t.a_mid = t.b_eid or t.a_mid = 0 or t.b_mid = 0) and t.a_name != 'chris'
```

Comment: You missed the recursive nature of the original query. I don't think your solution will walk the complete hierarchy.

Comment: Yea, I didn't think I hit the mark. I dig this question. Hoping to see more answers.